# CQRS - foreign key on read side database

Tags: foreign-keys, relational-database, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm working on my first project using CQRS, and some things are not really clear to me.

Suppose I have in my model some customers and every customers has a list of orders.

In my read model (supported by a standard relational database), I will have a projection with the list of all customers. Moreover I'll have a projection with the list of all orders.

In this second projection, does it make sense to have a foreign key to key table with all the customers? Or is it better the denormalize immediately and store in the table of the orders also all the relevant data of the customers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it depends on your requirements.

One school of thought is to denormalise the data for all your view models in so far as you would have one-table-per-view. On the other end of the spectrum you could keep a highly normalised database to support your views. You could also opt for somewhere in between. There are trade-offs in terms of speed, storage size, ease of use and scalability in these decisions. For example, if you had hundreds of very similar view models, it might make more sense to have a more normalised data model. Another example might be where one particular view generates orders of magnitude more traffic than any other view - you'd likely want to optimise this particular view more than the others. There isn't really a one-size-fits-all solution.

How about this crazy thought- *do both* ;) see which you prefer after working with them for a while. One of the great things about CQRS is you have the freedom to make these decisions. If you combine this with event sourcing and the ability to rebuild your views, then you can just change your mind later :)